# Fire an action as soon as an iframe appears using FirefoxDriver

Tags: c#, .net, iframe, selenium-webdriver

```
<iframe id="ifrm1">
    <head>
        <html>
            <body>
                <iframe id="ifrm2">
                    <head>
                        <html>
                            <body>
                                <a id="whatever" href="http://site1.com"></a>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                    </head>
                </iframe>
            </body>
        </html>
    </head>
</iframe>
```

c#

```
FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile("D:\\Documents and Settings\\username\\Application Data\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\myporfile");
dynamic ff = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary("D:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\Firefox.exe"), prof, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
ff.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));



try {
    ff.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://exemple.com");
    88:


    try {
        45:

        ff.SwitchTo().Frame("ifrm1");
        ff.SwitchTo().Frame("ifrm2");
    } catch (NoSuchFrameException exx) {
        goto 45;
    }

    try {
        66:
        IWebElement oo = ff.FindElement(By.TagName("a"));
        oo.Click();
        ff.Close();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        goto 66;
    }

} catch (WebDriverTimeoutException ex) {
    goto 88;
}
```

vb.net

```
 Dim prof As FirefoxProfile = New FirefoxProfile("D:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\myporfile")
        Dim ff = New FirefoxDriver(New FirefoxBinary("D:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe"), prof, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
        ff.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))



        Try
            ff.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://exemple.com")

88:         Try


45:             ff.SwitchTo().Frame("ifrm1")
                ff.SwitchTo().Frame("ifrm2")
   Catch exx As NoSuchFrameException
                GoTo 45
            End Try
            Try

66:             Dim oo As IWebElement = ff.FindElement(By.TagName("a"))
                oo.Click()
               ff.Close()
              Catch ex As NoSuchElementException
                GoTo 66
            End Try
        Catch ex As WebDriverTimeoutException

            GoTo 88
        End Try
```

so i handle the timeout exception and i handle NoSuchElementException to check if element is avaible , but sometimes fires , and sometimes does not ,

is there any better way to :

**1- not wait to document.Ready**

**2- monitor till the anchor inside second iframe appears and fire it**

thanks for help !

Comment: @Saifur what do u mean? .net aswell

Comment: What language binding you are using exactly? plus, if I am seeing it correcly the only issue is the finding `a` tag inside second `iframe`? correct?

Comment: @Saifur not only finding it , waiting it , as soon as it appears then firing it , im using vb.net/c# whatever ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , the trick was , on whene switching to the first iframe , and the second one is not yet loaded , i should switch back to default main content ..

```
ff.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))

//to start the job after 5 second , and skip waiting for all DOM document to be Ready !

   Try
            ff.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://exemple.com")

45         Try
           ff.SwitchTo().DefaultContent() // if ifrm1 is loaded and not iframe 2 , you should switch back to default !
           ff.SwitchTo().Frame("ifrm1")
           ff.SwitchTo().Frame("ifrm2")
           Dim oo As IWebElement = ff.FindElement(By.TagName("a"))
           oo.Click()
           ff.Close()
           Catch ex As Exception
                GoTo 45
            End Try
        Catch ex As WebDriverTimeoutException
//To Skip the wait of all document ...
            GoTo 45
End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

After you switch to the **Second `iframe`** You should wait for the element with `explicit` wait. But, you have to make sure that `Selenium` was able to set focus inside second `iframe`

```
//Define the time you want to wait while selenium is looking for the element.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement oo  = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElement(By.Id("ifrm2"));
});

//iframe found so use switchTo()
ff.SwitchTo().Frame("ifrm2")
```

Comment: well thanks for ur help , but , what if waiting spet by step , waitinf for 1st iframe , then waiting for 2nd iframe ??

Comment: Same implementation. Probably write a custom function to wait for the elements. You can use `WebDriverWait ` pretty much for any element. Such as `iframe1` , `iframe2`

Comment: well , question edited , if iframe2 appears , anchor will appears aswell , so i guess waiting for iframe2 is the target ..

Comment: Yes, then use the `wait` for `iframe` and then `switchTo()` to go inside the `iframe` and finally do `oo.Click()`

Comment: this works , but the problem still , the action will be done till Document is ready , i want to fire the action as soon as the iframe is ready , not all document

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the problem. If I did, then you have to wait for the `iframe` to exist. Correct? and, after switching the frame(unless you explicitly commands selenium to wait for `DOM` ready state ) it will not wait and execute next command

Comment: yeah , till iframe2 appears , fire the anchor inside it , this solution , it will fire anchor inside iframe2 till the document is ready , website many request , i have to wait for all requests be done , ...

Comment: +1 - on a different use case, i've been struggling with a combination of `thread.sleep()` and `await.task.delay()` in order to be sure that elements existed before referencing them. the penny dropped when seeing the `WebDriverWait` implementation -doh. looks like i've got a lot of (happy) refactoring to do :-)